# Como transferir dados de uma função para outra?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, variáveis

A ideia inicial do meu projeto pessoal era desenvolver um sistema básico para realizar a divisão de pagamento entre n clientes que consumiram n produtos, com o intuito de treinar minha habilidades.

Para isso, a ideia central seria alimentar dois blocos simples de input, sendo um para os clientes e outro para os produtos (com os preços), criando uma lista para o primeiro e outra lista para o segundo. É possível ver nos códigos que a maior parte do sistema já foi feito com as duas funções principais:

**HTML**

```js
var addCliente = document.getElementById("addCliente");
var addProduto = document.getElementById("addProduto");
var listaClientesContainer = document.getElementById("listaClientesContainer");
var listaProdutosContainer = document.getElementById("listaProdutosContainer");

addCliente.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addClienteFunction();
});
        
addProduto.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addProdutoFunction();
});
    
var contadorCliente = 0;

function addClienteFunction() {
    var nomeCliente = document.getElementById("nomeCliente");
            
    if (nomeCliente.value != "") {
        var postagemCliente = document.createElement("div");
        var dadosDoCliente = document.createElement("div");
        var areaDoValorDividido = document.createElement("div");
                
                
        listaClientesContainer.appendChild(postagemCliente);
                
        postagemCliente.classList.add("postagemCliente");
        postagemCliente.appendChild(dadosDoCliente);
                
        dadosDoCliente.classList.add("dadosDoCliente");
                
        postagemCliente.appendChild(areaDoValorDividido);   
      areaDoValorDividido.classList.add("areaDoValorDividido");
                
        dadosDoCliente.innerHTML += contadorCliente+1 + " - " + nomeCliente.value;
        areaDoValorDividido.innerHTML = "R$0";
        nomeCliente.value = "";
                
        contadorCliente++;
    }
}
          
var valorTotal = 0;
var contadorProduto = 0;
var valorDividido = 0;

function addProdutoFunction() {
    var nomeProduto = document.getElementById("nomeProduto");
    var precoProduto = document.getElementById("precoProduto");
            
    if ((nomeProduto.value != "") && (precoProduto.value != "") && (!isNaN(precoProduto.value))) {
        var postagemProduto = document.createElement("div");
                
                
        listaProdutosContainer.appendChild(postagemProduto);
                
        postagemProduto.classList.add("postagemProduto");
        postagemProduto.innerHTML += contadorProduto+1 + " - " + nomeProduto.value + " (R$" + precoProduto.value + ")";
                
        valorTotal += Number(precoProduto.value);
        valorDividido = valorTotal/contadorCliente;
        console.log(valorDividido);
                
        nomeProduto.value = "";
        precoProduto.value = "";
        contadorProduto++;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="areaClientes">
    <div id="clientesContainer">
         <input type="text" id="nomeCliente" placeholder="Adicionar novo cliente">
         <button id="addCliente">Adicionar</button>
         <button id="finalizarConta">Fechar Conta</button>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div id="areaProdutos">
     <div id="produtosContainer">
         <input type="text" id="nomeProduto" placeholder="Adicionar novo produto">
         <input type="text" id="precoProduto" placeholder="Adicionar preço do produto">
         <button id="addProduto">Adicionar</button>
     </div>
</div>
    
<div id="listaClientes">
    <div id="listaClientesContainer"></div>
</div>
    
<div id="listaProdutos">
    <div id="listaProdutosContainer"></div>
</div>
```

A questão neste caso é "simples": Eu consigo obter o valor que deve ser pago por cada um através da variável "valorDividido", mas não consigo inserir este valor na lista dos clientes, uma vez que não é possível acessar o "areaDoValorDividido", pois esta é uma variável presente apenas na outra função.

Sendo assim, eu queria saber se há alguma forma de inserir um comando na função "addProdutoFunction()" que altere algum conteúdo presente unicamente na função "addClienteFunction()".

Comment: Veja se é isso: vc adiciona um produto, o total da soma dos produtos é dividido entre os clientes. Ao adicionar um novo cliente, o valor é novamente dividido entre os clientes. Pelo que notei, o valor só é dividido quando um novo produto é adicionado, não quando é adicionado um novo cliente.

Comment: Isso mesmo, o valor é alterado apenas através da função que adiciona um novo produto, uma vez que há a adição de uma nova quantia ao montante total. Mas a minha duvida é sobre como seria possível adicionar na própria função de produtos um mecanismo para alterar a informação presente na lista dos clientes, para poder adicionar o valor resultante da divisão dessa nova quantia.

Comment: Seria melhor criar uma função separada que faz a divisão dos valores. Assim vc pode chamá-la nas duas outras funções.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro criar uma terceira função onde é feita a divisão dos valores. Isso deixará seu código bem mais flexível, pois assim você poderá chamá-la quando quiser nas outras funções.

Veja que abaixo criei a função `dividirValor()` e comentei algumas linhas que se tornaram desnecessárias:

```js
var addCliente = document.getElementById("addCliente");
var addProduto = document.getElementById("addProduto");
var listaClientesContainer = document.getElementById("listaClientesContainer");
var listaProdutosContainer = document.getElementById("listaProdutosContainer");

    addCliente.addEventListener("click", function() {
        addClienteFunction();
    });

    addProduto.addEventListener("click", function() {
        addProdutoFunction();
    });

    var contadorCliente = 0;
    function addClienteFunction() {
        var nomeCliente = document.getElementById("nomeCliente");

        if (nomeCliente.value != "") {
            var postagemCliente = document.createElement("div");
            var dadosDoCliente = document.createElement("div");
            var areaDoValorDividido = document.createElement("div");

            listaClientesContainer.appendChild(postagemCliente);
            postagemCliente.classList.add("postagemCliente");
            postagemCliente.appendChild(dadosDoCliente);
            dadosDoCliente.classList.add("dadosDoCliente");
            postagemCliente.appendChild(areaDoValorDividido);
            areaDoValorDividido.classList.add("areaDoValorDividido");

            dadosDoCliente.innerHTML += contadorCliente+1 + " - " + nomeCliente.value;
            areaDoValorDividido.innerHTML = "R$0";
            nomeCliente.value = "";

            contadorCliente++;
            
            dividirValor(); // chama a função para dividir os valores
            
        }
    }

    var valorTotal; // define o valor total
    var contadorProduto = 0;
    var valorDividido = 0;
    function addProdutoFunction() {
        var nomeProduto = document.getElementById("nomeProduto");
        var precoProduto = document.getElementById("precoProduto");

        if ((nomeProduto.value != "") && (precoProduto.value != "") && (!isNaN(precoProduto.value))) {
            var postagemProduto = document.createElement("div");

            listaProdutosContainer.appendChild(postagemProduto);
            postagemProduto.classList.add("postagemProduto");
            postagemProduto.innerHTML += contadorProduto+1 + " - " + nomeProduto.value + " (R$" + precoProduto.value + ")";

//            valorTotal += Number(precoProduto.value);
//            valorDividido = valorTotal/contadorCliente;
            console.log(valorDividido);
            
            dividirValor(); // chama a função para dividir os valores
            

            nomeProduto.value = "";
            precoProduto.value = "";
            contadorProduto++;
            }
    }
    
    function dividirValor(){

      valorTotal = 0; // reseta o valor total para 0
      var produtosValores = document.getElementsByClassName("postagemProduto"); // pega os produtos
      for(var x=0; x<produtosValores.length; x++){
         valorTotal += parseFloat(produtosValores[x].innerHTML.match(/R\$(\d+)/)[1]); // soma os valores
      }
      
      var areasValorDividido = document.getElementsByClassName("areaDoValorDividido"); // pega os clientes

      var numero_clientes = areasValorDividido.length; // conta os clientes
      if(numero_clientes){
         valorDividido = valorTotal/numero_clientes; // divide o total pelo número de clientes
         for(var x=0; x<areasValorDividido.length; x++){
            areasValorDividido[x].innerHTML = "R$"+valorDividido;
         }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="areaClientes">
    <div id="clientesContainer">
        <input type="text" id="nomeCliente" placeholder="Adicionar novo cliente">
        <button id="addCliente">Adicionar</button>
        <button id="finalizarConta">Fechar Conta</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="areaProdutos">
    <div id="produtosContainer">
        <input type="text" id="nomeProduto" placeholder="Adicionar novo produto">
        <input type="text" id="precoProduto" placeholder="Adicionar preço do produto">
        <button id="addProduto">Adicionar</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listaClientes">
    <div id="listaClientesContainer">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listaProdutos">
    <div id="listaProdutosContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você disse que a ideia é treinar as habilidades, vou pular a questão apontada pelo Sam de ser melhor uma função para fazer a divisão (com quem eu concordo) e focar didaticamente no que você perguntou.

Sua questão se resume a **ESCOPO**.

No seu caso, a variável `areaDoValorDividido` tem como escopo a função `addClienteFunction`, portanto ela não pode ser acessada a partir da outra função a não ser que seja passada para ela de alguma forma.

As duas respostas mais simples são:

**1.** Na real, sua variável `areaDoValorDividido` é apenas um ponteiro para a `div`, que por sua vez é um elemento do `DOM`. O `DOM` não está dentro do escopo da sua função; ele faz parte do `document` -- portanto, mesmo sem acesso à variável `areaDoValorDividido` na outra função, você pode simplesmente buscar a `div` diretamente, a partir da outra função, e manipular essa `div` como quiser. Pelo código que você postou, a melhor forma de identificar a div `areaDoValorDividido` é pela classe (já que você não deu `name` nem `id`). Você consegue acessar por um `querySelector`.

É só chegar na outra função, `addProdutoFunction`, e colocar:

```
const areaDoValorDividido = document.querySelector('div.areaDoValorDividido')
```

A partir daí, você terá, no escopo da função `addProdutoFunction`, uma variável também com o nome `areaDoValorDividido`, com duas possibilidades de conteúdo: caso no documento HTML não tenha sido encontrado um elemento `div` com a classe `areaDoValorDividido`, a variável terá o valor `null`; caso o elemento já tenha sido criado pela outra função, a variável apontará para a mesma `div` que a variável de mesmo nome na outra função. Aí, você pode usar normalmente (`areaDoValorDividido.innerHTML`, `areaDoValorDividido.innerText`, `areaDoValorDividido.textContent`, etc).

Nesse cenário, você terminou com duas variáveis diferentes, uma no escopo de cada função, ambas com o mesmo nome, apontando para a mesma `div` e podendo, na prática, serem utilizadas da mesma forma.

**2.** No seu caso tanto faz, pois você pode acessar o elemento que você quer mesmo sem acessar a variável . Contudo, se você precisasse **realmente** acessar a variável, o que geralmente se faz é **subir/elevar o escopo**.

Em vez de criar as divs `postagemCliente`, `dadosDoCliente` e `areaDoValorDividido` de forma dinâmica, já que esses 3 elementos sempre estarão lá, você pode já deixá-los pré-criados no seu HTML, de preferência dando um `id` a cada um com os respectivos nomes. Como eles não terão conteúdo, eles não aparecerão na janela (isso pode mudar de acordo com o CSS). Aí, você declara e seta essas três variáveis no escopo superior, fora dessas 3 funções, e passa as variáveis como parâmetros. Ficaria algo assim:

```
const elements = {
    addCliente: document.getElementById("addCliente"),
    addProduto: document.getElementById("addProduto"),
    listaClientesContainer: document.getElementById("listaClientesContainer"),
    listaProdutosContainer: document.getElementById("listaProdutosContainer"),
    nomeCliente: document.getElementById("nomeCliente"),
    postagemCliente: document.getElementById("postagemCliente"),
    dadosDoCliente: document.getElementById("dadosDoCliente"),
    areaDoValorDividido: document.getElementById("areaDoValorDividido")
}

const values = {
    contadorCliente: 0,
    valorTotal: 0,
    contadorProduto: 0,
    valorDividido: 0
}

elements.addCliente.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addClienteFunction(elements, values);
});
        
elements.addProduto.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addProdutoFunction(elements, values);
});
    
function addClienteFunction(elements, values) {
    if (elements.nomeCliente.value == "") return;
    values.contadorCliente++;
    elements.dadosDoCliente.innerHTML += values.contadorCliente + " - " + elements.nomeCliente.value;
    elements.areaDoValorDividido.innerHTML = "R$0";
    elements.nomeCliente.value = "";
}
              
function addProdutoFunction(elements, values) {
   ... //Aqui você adapta da mesma forma aos objetos recebidos como parâmetros
}
```